# Reliable source for getting free land use map for Ahmedabad city, India?

Tags: geospatial, india

Could you please help me to find out the land use map for Ahmedabad city, India preferably in GIS format (Shapefile).

Comment: For Land Use, you will likely have to contact the locality directly or look at their website for a link.  Have you tried direct contact?

Comment: Where have you looked?

Comment: I tried http://data.un.org/ but didn't see anything that jumped out at me. You can poke around more as I don't have time right now.